# Reading subcolumn of an excel sheet into python and show them in a dataframe(in streamlit) in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, streamlit

I have been working on an excel sheet  and trying to read subcolumns and show them in a table using streamlit for creating an UI.
I am not able to read the subcolumn and put them in a table. Below are some code snippets and excel screesnhots.
If anyone has an Idea then, Please help in resolving this.

code:

```
st.set_page_config(page_title="KPI Documentation",
                    page_icon=":bar_chart:",
                    layout="wide")

file_path='file.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(file_path,index_col=None,na_values=['NA'],usecols="B,C,E,F,J:O")
df_new=df.set_axis(df.iloc[0].values,axis=1)
df_new=df.iloc[1:]


agree=st.button('click to see the table:')
if agree:
    st.subheader("Information")
    st.dataframe(df)
```

Excel:
[Excel columns example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7smH.png)

Table I got as an output:
[Table output in streamlit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eujul.png)

Comment: have you tried multi header option?
like: `df= pd.read_excel('ExcelFile.xlsx', header=[0, 1])`

Comment: In the screenshot you only show that the columns don't have the name Timeline. You can simply assign the name to them, if the content is actually there. What's the content of the Unnamed columns?